# TypeError: get_win_percentage() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self):
        self.team_name = 'none'
        self.team_wins = 0
        self.team_losses = 0

    # TODO: Define get_win_percentage()
    def get_win_percentage():
        team_wins()
        team_losses()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    team = Team()
   
    team_name = input()
    team_wins = input()
    team_losses = input()
    
    team.team_name = team_name
    team.team_wins = team_wins
    team.team_losses = team_losses
    
    if team.get_win_percentage() >= 0.5:
        print('Congratulations, Team', team.team_name,'has a winning average!')
    else:
        print('Team', team.team_name, 'has a losing average.')
```

Comment: There's some confusion here... `get_win_percentage` is an instance method, yet you're calling `team_wins` and `team_losses` as if they're global functions, yet they are properties on the `Team` class.

Answer (score 0):

Add `self` to the function definition or declare as a `@staticmethod`.